# get next and previous item of a selected item in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-8

Say you have items [2,**4**,*5*,**8**,3] and you would like to get numbers around **5** which are **4** and **8**.
how do you do it in **laravel**
thanks.

Comment: In a nutshell, you'd need to get the index of `5` (which is 2), then get the values of index 1 and 3. That being said, what have you tried? Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service; you're expected to make an effort to solve your own issue before asking for help.

Comment: seems i phrased the question poorly, i wanted to get the posts next to the selected post

Comment: No worries! I was wondering if that what you were interested in :) Glad you got it working regardless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem

```
   public function show(Blog $blog)
{
    $next = Blog::where('id', '>', $blog->id)
        ->oldest('id')
        ->first();
    $previous = Blog::where('id', '<', $blog->id)
        ->latest('id')
        ->first();
    return view('dashboard.Blog.show',compact('blog','previous','next'));
}
```

[laravel-getting-the-previous-and-next-records](https://itnext.io/laravel-getting-the-previous-and-next-records-60a8cf109daa)